# Redirect to action controller by JavaScript with parameters (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Currently when I make a redirect to action of controller with parameters I have to make like this:

```
window.location.href = "/Controller/Action/?parameterId=" + this.Id();
```

But Really I woud like that was like this:

```
window.location.href = "/Controller/Action/" + this.Id();
```

Why ?? Because I thing that looks fine and second is more oriented to route pattern of ASP MVC

Its posible ???

PD: Im using knockout js ...

Comment: Depending how you defined your route.

Comment: The second will work if the parameter of the method is named `id` and your using the default route. If the parameter is named `parameterId` then you need to define a route that has `url: "{controller}/{action}/{parameterId}",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server code is ASP.NET MVC then you probably already have RouteConfig.cs:
You could use RouteConfig.cs and define your route:
Normally you would define a RouteConfig class and under

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
routes.MapRoute("myRoute","AreaName", new {controller="ControllerName", 
action="ActionName",id=UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

If hosting on IIS version > 6.0, you could use URL Rewrite 2.0 if your hosting the site on IIS and define the routing rule in IIS for that site.